# How to use the TBB task_arena class with enqueue and wait_until_empty

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, tbb

I am looking for an example of how to use the **Threaded Building Blocks** [task_arena](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468318) class with `enqueue` and `wait_until_empty`.

Here is the process I am following. As described in the documentation above, add these includes:

```
#define TBB_PREVIEW_TASK_ARENA 1
#include "tbb/task.h"
#include “tbb/task_arena.h”
```

Then, create the tasks with `tbb::task::allocate_root` and enqueue them using `tbb::arena::enqueue`.

However, I receive this error on the arena `wait_until_empty()` method:

**error: ‘class tbb::interface7::task_arena’ has no member named ‘wait_until_empty’**

I am using the most current release version 4.3, update 3.

Please provide a simple working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `wait_until_empty` was removed from class `task_arena` in recent updates. Unfortunately, the documentation at software.intel.com which you refer to is not updated yet. I recommend to use the documentation at [threadingbuildingblocks.org](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/appendices/community_preview_features/task_arena_cls.htm) which is more up to date.

The example in that documentation page demonstrates how you can combine `task_arena` and `task_group` to achieve functionality similar to `wait_until_empty`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The scenario is: you have a simple program that starts, enqueues many tasks using ```enqueue```, and then terminates. How should you make sure that all the tasks have completed before the program terminates?

Comment: It would be great if the documentation were updated with additional examples using ```enqueue```.